# Aside from the resulting git tree structure, are there any important differences between git pull vs git fetch + git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, pull, git-fetch, git-status

I've worked on a dev team that preferred to use the method of `git fetch` and then `git rebase` rather than the method of `git pull`, before git pushing any changes to avoid merge conflicts.

Is there a specific reason besides the difference in the visual tree structure? According to http://mattsnider.com/git-rebase-versus-git-pull/ `fetch` & `rebase`

> "will produce a cleaner history, without extraneous merge commits"

but between the two methods are there any other reasons to choose one over the other?

Comment: You can configure `git pull` to run `git rebase` instead of `git merge` as its second step. In the end, it doesn't make much difference to *operation*, but I think `git pull` does a steep dis-service to *humans* by hiding the fact that there are actually two steps involved: `git fetch`, and then that second step. The `pull` command is also syntactically dangerous due to this same human failing: it's too easy to run `git pull origin b1 b2` and end up doing an octopus merge, because it *looks* like `git pull` does something magic, but it really doesn't.

Comment: `git merge` creates a merge commit when it's not a fast-forward merge. A merge commit doesn't invoke a hook like `commit-msg`. In some cases, when you need `commit-msg` to do something with every new commit, the merge commit is ignored unless you amend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`

`git pull --rebase` or `git pull -r`= `git fetch` + `git rebase`

No more, no less ;-) there is no magic. 
So you could do the second.

The main advantage of doing fetch then rebase in 2 distinct steps is that the first doesn't modify your local branch (absolutely no risks) and so you could do it every time (you could even create a task that run it periodically).

And once fetched, you could look at the history, compare it to your commits, and decide what you want to do and when...